# Powershell Remoting for microsoft exchange using winrm is failing with below error

Tags: winrm

Im trying to execute microsoft exchange command from remote client using winrm. Connection established successfully, im able to execute basic commands(Get-Date..) and able to execute some commands related to AD. But when it comes to Exchange related commands(Get-Mailbox) it fails with below error.

Active Directory operation failed on . The supplied credential for 'domain/user' is invalid.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ADInvalidCredentialException

any help is apprecited...

Note: i have tried below command before executing above command.
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn. no error while snapin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the credentials into the PSSession and then execute the actual commands.

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName HYDIN001 -Credential $Credential
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited
```

Comment: $Credential = Get-Credential
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <host> -Credential $Credential
These two commands executes successfully and a session is opened then below command also executes fine. "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn"

But Get-Mailbox comamnds returns below error "Active Directory operation failed on . The supplied credential for 'domain/user' is invalid. + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], ADInvalidCredentialException".

Comment: so found in some other questions that we need to use below command to connect with exchange server 
$sess = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://<FQDN>/PowerShell/ -Authentication Basic  -Credential $creds
But this command fails with Access denied error  "Connecting to remote server "<FQDN>" failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
Help topic.
At line:1 char:10"

Comment: I hope the computer name you are passing the mail server hostname. `-ComputerName HYDIN001` Can you confirm on it.